# Remove space between rectangles html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I use a `For Loop` to create 100 somewhat rectangles inside the `HTMLCanvasElement`.

But there are white spaces between the rectangles when **ZOOMING** in or out (with the scrolling functions on a mouse or touchpad). Now, adding a stroke to the rectangles will solve the area, but then the rectangles wont be perfectly aligned anymore.

[image: rectangles with white space]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

I've also taken a look at [Uint8ClampedArray](https://www.javascripture.com/Uint8ClampedArray) to create a custom `ImageData` `Object`. But I've come to the conclusion that `Uint8ClampedArray` isn't going to be a  solution to this problem.

```js
var canvas = $('#canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d"),
  win = $(window),
  ww = win.outerWidth(),
  wh = win.outerHeight(),
  scale = 1,
  pixelSize = 10 * scale,
  wx = 0,
  wy = 0,
  sx = 0,
  sy = 0;

var settings = {
  grid: true
}

var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  rx: 0,
  ry: 0,
  button: 0
};

function zoom(f) {
  return Math.floor(f * scale);
}

function zoomX(x) {
  return Math.floor((x - wx) * scale + sx);
}

function zoomY(y) {
  return Math.floor((y - wy) * scale + sy);
}

function zoomX_INV(x) {
  return Math.floor((x - sx) * (1 / scale) + wx);
}

function zoomY_INV(y) {
  return Math.floor((y - sy) * (1 / scale) + wy);
}

function setBackground(color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, ww, wh);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawPixel(x1, y1, fill) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(zoomX(x1 * pixelSize), zoomY(y1 * pixelSize), zoom(pixelSize), zoom(pixelSize));
  ctx.fillStyle = fill;
  ctx.fill();
  //  below wont fix it
  // ctx.strokeStyle = fill;
  // ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  // ctx.stroke();
}

function drawGrid() {
  //  var offsetX = Math.floor(wx / pixelSize) * pixelSize - wx,
  //   offsetY = Math.floor(wy / pixelSize) * pixelSize - wy;

  //  ctx.beginPath();

  //  ctx.moveTo(0, pixelSize);
  //  ctx.lineTo(0, wh);

  // //  for(var x = 0; x < ww; x += pixelSize * scale) {
  // //   ctx.moveTo(zoomX(x), zoomY(0));
  // //   ctx.lineTo(zoomX(x), zoomY(wh));
  // //  }

  // //  for(var y = 0; y < wh; y += pixelSize * scale) {
  // //   ctx.moveTo(zoomX(0), zoomY(y));
  // //         ctx.lineTo(zoomX(ww), zoomY(y));
  // //  }

  //  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  //  ctx.lineWidth = .5;
  //     ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ww, wh);

  setBackground('white');

  for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      drawPixel(x, y, 'green');
      drawPixel(x + 12, y + 12, 'skyblue');
    }
  }
  drawPixel(11, 11, 'green');

  // if (settings.grid) {
  //  drawGrid();
  // }
}

function resize() {

  ww = win.outerWidth();
  wh = win.outerHeight();

  canvas.get(0).width = ww;
  canvas.get(0).height = wh;

  draw();
}

function init() {
  resize();
}

canvas.on('mousemove mousedown mouseup mouseout', function(e) {
  if (e.type === "mousedown") {
    mouse.button = 1;
  } else if (e.type === "mouseup" || event.type === "mouseout") {
    mouse.button = 0;
  }

  mouse.bounds = canvas.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();

  mouse.x = e.clientX - mouse.bounds.left;
  mouse.y = e.clientY - mouse.bounds.top;

  var xx = mouse.rx;
  var yy = mouse.ry;

  mouse.rx = zoomX_INV(mouse.x);
  mouse.ry = zoomY_INV(mouse.y);

  if (mouse.button === 1) {
    wx -= mouse.rx - xx;
    wy -= mouse.ry - yy;
    mouse.rx = zoomX_INV(mouse.x);
    mouse.ry = zoomY_INV(mouse.y);
  }

  draw();
});

canvas.on('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    scale = Math.min(2, scale * 1.1);
  } else {
    scale = Math.max(0.5, scale * (1 / 1.1));
  }

  wx = mouse.rx;
  wy = mouse.ry;
  sx = mouse.x;
  sy = mouse.y;

  mouse.rx = zoomX_INV(mouse.x);
  mouse.ry = zoomY_INV(mouse.y);

  draw();
});

win.on('load resize', function() {
  init();
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper #controls {
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper #canvas {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
  image-rendering: -o-pixelated;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="controls"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: +1 from me, as this isn't a bad question, nor bad formatted. It has code, a working example, OP tried to solve it... Some people just want to see the world burn.

Comment: Do you mean for example that the green rectangle is build from smaller rectangles and you don't want to see the whitespace inside the green rectangle. Or do you mean that there is whistespace between the green and blue rectangle?

Comment: @mrdeadsven there's whitespace between every rectangle: between the 100 green rectangles AND between the 100 skyblue rectangles. Run the code snippet and try zooming in/out

Comment: aha I see, that one is actually weird because the more I zoom it changes continuously. Sometimes it's between all the rectangles and sometimes I only see 1 white space. One thing I did notice is that it is corresponding to the background color. A "hot fix" for this might be to retrieves the height width and position in the canvas of a rectangle and give that rectangle a corresponding background color. This way the whitespace won't occur. But a the moment I'm still thinking of a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the whitespace come from your `Math.floor` in all of your zoom functions, which give you approximated values for drawing

I don't know exactly what's wrong with your code, but I was able to achieve what you want using `ctx.scale(x, y)`. However, it doesn't exactly seem to work with your code...

https://jsfiddle.net/amrg2d3s/

Comment: It does reduce the width of the white lines. But unfortunately they're still very much visible! So, this is definitely not the answer I'm looking for. Also, when answering a question, try to provide your answer with some code to prove that your answer is the correct answer. Since I included my code in my question, you can easily copy it and adjust it. :)

Comment: This seems like the better solution! Using [the CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale)! I selected this as the best answer and I gave the bounty to you for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scaling the context (`canvas.getContext`), scale the rectangles with fixed width and height.

`size = Math.floor(original_el_size * cameraZoom)`

and draw rectangles in cycle inside canvas

Answer (score -1):

I would add comment but I don't have enough reputations. Try this

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        drawPixel(x, y, 'green');
        drawPixel(x + 11, y + 11, 'skyblue');
    }
}
drawPixel(10, 10, 'green');
```

Just manipulated some numbers

Comment: This does not work. It shouldn't matter what position the rectangles are drawn.